# How to get Android Studio to use 'java_out' and not 'javanano_out'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, protocol-buffers

I'm migrating an existing project to Android Studio and the new gradle build system.  This project uses version 2.6.1 of Protocol Buffers and I am having a tough time getting it to build the .proto files.

I installed this plugin: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.google.protobuf
I followed the instructions here on setting it up: https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin

I update my project 'build.gradle' as followed:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.0'
    }
}
```

I update the module 'build.gradle' as followed:

```
android{
    ...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            proto {
                srcDir 'src/main/proto'
            }
        }
    }

    protobuf {
        protoc  {
            path =  file('../../../tools/protocolBuffers/protoc.exe')
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

When I build I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':uidroid:generateXoomVerificationReleaseProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-protos\main: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-include-protos\main: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\src\xoomVerificationRelease\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-protos\xoomVerificationRelease: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-include-protos\xoomVerificationRelease: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\src\release\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-protos\release: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-include-protos\release: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\src\xoom\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-protos\xoom: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-include-protos\xoom: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\src\verification\proto: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-protos\verification: warning: directory does not exist.
C:\Software\Vivia\Limited\ui_test\Sourcecode\pluto\android\UIDroid\uidroid\build\extracted-include-protos\verification: warning: directory does not exist.
--javanano_out: protoc-gen-javanano: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. Why doesn't it create the directories in the build folder itself?
   I seems like I should have to create it as it's for generated code.
2. How do I get the build to use 'java_out' and not 'javanano_out'?
   The build never used java nano and while I'm not opposed to changing I want to get the build working has how it was before first as not to create to many variables.

I tried the tricks on the github page like:

```
{ task ->
  task.builtins {
    remove javanano
    java { }
  }
}
```

with no success.  This just caused more errors which may be due to me not using it correctly and if so please tell me the proper place to put the above code.

I guess if the only way to do this is to use javanano, then how do I get it as where to get this is not too obvious to me.  I've looked for more information about it at: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers to not much success.

Thanks to anybody that can help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already figured out what was the issue, but I've just recently had the same problem so let me post the solution here for anyone else who stumbles on this.

I did some research and it seems it is not possible to prevent this plugin to use javanano. I might be wrong, so if anyone else has better info please share with us. :)

So, assuming we must use javanano here is what I did:

First, checkout or download Googles protobuf/javanano from https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/javanano.
Create jar archive using these source files (compile *.java and create jar from *.class files). Add created jar to your project (place it in libs folder and modify build.gradle file to compile it).

Next, modify protobuf section in your build.gradle file to use generated protoc binaries instead of local protoc:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-alpha-3'
    }
}
```

This is described in protobuf-gradle-plugin README under Customizing Protobuf compilation: https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin.

Sync, and rebuild your project. That should do it. Hope it helps.

Cheers